# django save data from form

Tags: python, django, forms

I want to add a tags to the question. Instead of this, question title changed to content of the list_tags.

For example:

```
class NewAskForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=80)
    content_question = forms.CharField()
    tags = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=False)

def newask(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewAskForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        newask = Question(title = form.cleaned_data['title'])
        newask.content_question = form.cleaned_data['content_question']
        newask.id_user_id = request.user.id
        newask.creation_date_question = datetime.now()
        list_tags = form.cleaned_data['tags']
        new_tag = Tag(content_tag = list_tags.split(',', 1))
        new_tag.save()
        newask.save()
        newask.tags.add(new_tag)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/ask')
    else:
        form = NewAskForm()

    return render(request, 'ask/newask.html', {'form': form })
```

what am I doing wrong?

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    content_tag = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __unicode__(self):  
        return self.content_tag

class Question(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='tags')
```

Comment: @Andrey Nelubin, thanks, I changed the id of field, but i did not change name of field. I thought it does not affect.

Comment: You have a syntax issue on your code, `if form.is_valid():` should be inside the `if request.method == 'POST'`, you cannot validate the form if you don't receive a POST or the variable form doesn't exist

Comment: What do you have inside `newask.tags.all()` after the title of the question changed ? and when you do `new_tag = Tag(content_tag = list_tags.split(',', 1))` what do you have inside `list_tags` ? Because after `list_tags.split(',', 1)`, you get a list, are you trying to assing a list to a charfield ?